# How to make the dropdown list scrollable using ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a project where I need to make a dropdown which will be having following facility.

1. Move Up/Down with arrow key
2. Scrollable
3. Search

Here is the code I have tried so far to create the dropdown.

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';


class Dropdown extends React.Component {
constructor(){
 super();

 this.state = {
       displayMenu: false,
     };

  this.showDropdownMenu = this.showDropdownMenu.bind(this);
  this.hideDropdownMenu = this.hideDropdownMenu.bind(this);

};

showDropdownMenu(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ displayMenu: true }, () => {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.hideDropdownMenu);
    });
  }

  hideDropdownMenu() {
    this.setState({ displayMenu: false }, () => {
      document.removeEventListener('click', this.hideDropdownMenu);
    });

  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div  className="dropdown" style = {{background:"red",width:"200px"}} >
            <div className="button" onClick={this.showDropdownMenu}> My Setting </div>
            {
              this.state.displayMenu ? (
                <ul>
                      <li><a className="active" href="#Create Page">Create Page</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#Manage Pages">Manage Pages</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#Create Ads">Create Ads</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#Activity Logs">Activity Logs</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#Setting">Setting</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#Log Out">Log Out</a></li>
                </ul>
              ): ( null )
            }
        </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Dropdown;
```

### Please help me with the code to make it scrollable. Thanks in advance!

Comment: add fixed height to the block and add `overflow-y:scroll`

Comment: Can you please add some lines of code to it,because by adding >' overflow-y:scroll ' in style part is not reflecting the things that I was looking for, sir.

Comment: Please check the stackblitz implementation of the qustion https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nhxace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**App.js**

```
// App.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './style.css';

const App = () => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

  return(
    <div className="container">
      <button onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)}>Dropdown<button>
      <ul className={`${toggle ? show : ''}`}>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>four</li>
        <li>five</li>
        <li>six</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**style.css**

```
// style.css
.container{
  position: relative;
}

ul{
  height: 50px;       // fixed height
  overflow: hidden;   // then set overflow to hidden in all respects
  overflow-y: scroll; // At the end only from the top and bottom overflow to scrollable
  background: 'red';
  display: none;
}

.show{
    display: block !important;
}
```